# display some post from posting date to expiry date in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i am doing task in which some post are created and i want to display post in posting date that i have selected and expired the post, the date at which expiry date. overall meaning meaning post is display in between only posting date and expiry date. whis is changes in my query

my query is

```
$query = DB::table('jobpost')
            ->select('jobpost.*') 
            ->where('jobpost.postStatus','Open')
            ->where('jobpost.postingdate','>=',$currentDate)
            ->get();
```

Comment: What you'r trying to achieve here btw?

Comment: @Mansjoer i am posting some jobpost and table contain posting date and expiry date column for each job. Now i when i added job from admin side, in a user side job will show on posting date and show upto expiry date after expiry date  that system automatically disable this post. i am new in laravel

Comment: So what is the problem then?, maybe you can use simple code by importing the model into your controller. I think you should post more information about what you'r trying to achieve, like what did you use to show the `$currentDate`